# jQuery Dynamic Masking

Tags: jquery, mask, masking

I have used jQuery Masking plugin in my App.

Link is given here.

https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

I need the dynamic masking like.

Sometime I will need to use like this
000-00-0
0000000-00-0

Suppose I write 50000 then it would become 50-00-0

Suppose I write 500000 then it would become 500-00-0

So my first section will contain 1 to 7 different numbers.

So how i can do this.

Simple masking i am using like in below.

```
$("input[name='mask']").mask("9999999-99-9");
```

**Solution**

```
var my_condition = true;
    $("input[name='mask']").on('click focus', function(){ 
       $("input[name='mask']").unmask();
       my_condition = true;
    });  
    $("input[name='mask']").on('change paste', function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length;
            if(my_condition) {
             switch(len) {
                 case 5:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('99-99-9');
                     break;
                 case 6:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('999-99-9');
                     break;
                 case 7:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('9999-99-9');
                     break;
                 case 8:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('99999-99-9');
                     break;
                 case 9:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('999999-99-9');
                     break;
                 case 10:
                     $("input[name='mask']").mask('9999999-99-9');
                     break;
                 default:
                      $("input[name='mask']").mask('9999');   
             }
             my_condition = false;
         }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqkhvauo/4/) to demonstrate how would I tackle that problem.

Here is my JS code:

```
$("#input").change(function(){
 var len = $(this).val().length;


if(len == 4)
    $(this).mask('99-99');
else if (len == 5)
  $(this).mask('999-99');
else if (len == 6)
  $(this).mask('9-99999');
})

$("#input").focus(function(){
 var val = $(this).val().replace("-",""); //remove the dashes from the old masked value
 $(this).mask("9999999999"); //set to maximum length
 $(this).val(val);
})
```

The problem with `.mask()` is that it sets a maximum length for the input field which means that if you set a mask `"99-99"`, you can't write more than 4 digits in the input field.My solution is to set the mask to `"9999999999"` when the input gets focused then set the proper mask after changing the value. You'll have to change the `change()` (accidental pun) event to fit your needs.

Implementation flaw: User cannot see mask while typing

Comment: @JohnCraig :( That's bad. I don't see any other way to do it using this library. What's your concern with my implementation?